# permission denied after chmod

Tags: php, apache, unlink

I know this question was answered very much but I don't understand from the answers.

```
<?php

$link = __DIR__.'\ddd\\';
$files = scandir($link);
 chmod($link.$vedio,0777);
 array_shift($files);
array_shift($files);
foreach($files as $numper => $vedios){
echo $numper.".".$vedios."<br/>";
chmod($link.$vedio,777);
unlink($link.$vedio);
};
```

Not working:

> Warning: unlink(C:\AppServ\www\pco\ddd): Permission denied in
>   C:\AppServ\www\pco\scandir.php on line 12

Comment: What operating system/environment is this running under?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

you are missing 0

it should be

```
chmod($link.$vedio,0777);
```

in your 8th line. [source](http://php.net/manual/en/function.chmod.php)

Comment: in the 3th line

Comment: No, 3rd line is correct, the one in the 8th is missing a 0

Comment: 0.ba.zip

Warning: unlink(C:\AppServ\www\pco\ddd\): Permission denied in C:\AppServ\www\pco\scandir.php on line 12
1.dd.jnt

Warning: unlink(C:\AppServ\www\pco\ddd\): Permission denied in C:\AppServ\www\pco\scandir.php on line 12
2.sd.psd

Warning: unlink(C:\AppServ\www\pco\ddd\): Permission denied in C:\AppServ\www\pco\scandir.php on line 12

Comment: after i add a 0  Permission denied too

Comment: Ohh, you are running on windows. chmod doesn't work on windows, you'll need to change permissions on the folder and make it's children inherit these permissions